# Flash Pro: Collision of objects only works correctly when on Frame 1

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, collision

as you may have noticed just by reading the title it is quite hard to summarize the problem,
which is probably why I couldn't find a solution anywhere.

I am currently working on a flash game using adobe flash pro CC.

I started by creating the first level of my sidescrolling game and got everything to work just as I wanted it to. All my work was on a single frame (frame 1) and on a single layer and it worked fine.
However, when I then went on to move the frame a little further back and added frames in front of it for the menu I encountered a problem.
When I "gotoAndStop" to the frame with my game content on it, everything works except the collision between my character and my objects. My character is now sunk into the "floor object" about have his size, while when i move the frame back to "frame 1" everything works fine again.

I am losing my mind over this. Please help me :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in flash when you start changing a dynamic property such as x or y, that object will be independent from the keyframe where it originally was ~forever~, even if you go back to the original keyframe. therefore if you start some enterframe and change the playhead afterwards you will get some awkward (but expected) behaviour.

ideally, jump to the game keyframe and just then call whatever methods needed to start the game.